# Difference between two lines, ignoring some lines

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a workflow which runs the night, depending of the planning. Sometimes it succeeds, sometimes not. When it fails, I want to know for how many days it's been KO, but without counting the day where it is not expected

I have the following input data :

```
ID    Date        Status
1     20170616    KO
1     20170615    OK
1     20170614    OK
1     20170613    OK
1     20170612    KO
1     20170611    NO RUN
1     20170610    NO RUN
1     20170609    KO
1     20170608    OK
1     20170607    KO
1     20170506    OK
```

NO RUN means it did not run, but it was expected.

And I want :

```
ID    Date        Status       NbDayKO
1     20170616    KO           1
1     20170615    OK           0
1     20170614    NO RUN       0
1     20170613    OK           0
1     20170612    KO           2
1     20170611    NO RUN       1
1     20170610    NO RUN       1
1     20170609    KO           1
1     20170608    OK           0
1     20170607    KO           1
1     20170606    OK           0
```

I always have one line per day. If necessary, the NO RUN lines can be removed, resulting in jump in the dates.

I can get the last day on OK with the lead function, but I do not succeed to do the difference of days without counting the NO RUN days.

I tried to do a sum with :

```
sum(
CASE WHEN Status = 'KO' THEN 1
     WHEN Status = 'NO RUN' THEN 0
     ELSE NULL
END) over(partition by idStatus order by date)
```

I expected it to reset the value to NULL each time it encountered `OK` but the `sum` function ignores `NULL`

I also tried several other thing, mostly based on analytic queries, but without succees.

Any idea on how to do that ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a way of doing this with two levels of window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when status = 'KO' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id, cume_ko order by date) as nbDayKO
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when status = 'OK' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by date) as cume_ko
      from t
     ) t;
```

The subquery defines groups of rows that are delimited by OKs.  The outer `sum()` then enumerates the 'KO' status within each group.

Comment: Simple and easy, exactly what I needed. Thank you.